# How to set breakpoint to obtain address of a function in fork.c , in the kernel source?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

Good day to all. I have this query which I hope someone is able to help me with. I forward my gratitude and thanks in advance. I had done hours of search but unable  to find a solution.

My problem:

I need to obtain the address of the " security_task_create(clone_flags)" function the following code snippet (located in line 926 ,fork.c as per "/usr/src/linux-2.6.27/kernel/fork.c") -:

```
************************************ ************************************ 

static struct task_struct *copy_process(unsigned long clone_flags,
unsigned long stack_start,
struct pt_regs *regs,
unsigned long stack_size,
int __user *child_tidptr,
struct pid *pid,
int trace)

{

int retval;
struct task_struct *p;
int cgroup_callbacks_done = 0;

if ((clone_flags & (CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_FS)) == (CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_FS))
return ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);

/*
* Thread groups must share signals as well, and detached threads
* can only be started up within the thread group.
*/
if ((clone_flags & CLONE_THREAD) && !(clone_flags & CLONE_SIGHAND))
return ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);

/*
* Shared signal handlers imply shared VM. By way of the above,
* thread groups also imply shared VM. Blocking this case allows
* for various simplifications in other code.
*/
if ((clone_flags & CLONE_SIGHAND) && !(clone_flags & CLONE_VM))
return ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);

****retval = security_task_create(clone_flags);****
if (retval)
goto fork_out;

retval = -ENOMEM;
p = dup_task_struct(current);
if (!p)
goto fork_out;

rt_mutex_init_task(p);
************************************ ************************************
```

I've enabled KDB access over keyboard in my Fedora Core 16 machine with kernel 3.1.7. Upon entering KDB console i.e. " kdb[0]>  , I typed  security_task_create and a hex address e.g. 0x0040118e is displayed.

My Questions:

1. Is the displayed hex address - the address of the security_task_create upon the kernel loaded?

2.If not, how am I able to obtain the address of the  security_task_create  function? How do I configure KDB to obtain the address of the  security_task_create function?

1. What I have in mind is to insert a breakpoint at line 926 in fork.c using KDB when the kernel runs security_task_create in memory. If such is indeed the proper solution, how do I obtain the address of  security_task_create using such method?

Comment: Why do you need the address ? I think the kernel debugger supports setting breakpoints using function names and filename:lineno format.

Answer (score 0):

For getting address of any symbol in kernel use [System.map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System.map) file simply.

`CONFIG_KALLSYMS` is needs to be enabled in kernel configuration for getting all symbols in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Just grep for printk in your source directory and I'm sure you'll find tons of examples.

```
printk(KERN_INFO "fork(): process `%s' used deprecated "
                    "clone flags 0x%lx\n",
                get_task_comm(comm, current),
                clone_flags & CLONE_STOPPED);
```